# How to add parameter in column name?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dynamic-sql

Query:

```
declare @Year  varchar(max) ;
SET @Year=  CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)
select 1 as 'apr-' + cast(@year as varchar(10))
```

Error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
>   Incorrect syntax near '+'.

output like :

```
apr-2017
1
```

Comment: You must use dynamic sql for this

Comment: ... because table and column names are fix in a SQL query; they cannot be replaced by data (e.g. the current year). And why not simply call the column `this_year` instead of `2017`? Then you'd have a pure SQL solution and would know what column to get when calling it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
 declare @Year  varchar(max) ;
 SET @Year=  CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR)

 declare @cmd nvarchar(max)
 select @cmd = 'select 1 as ''apr-' + cast(@year as varchar(10)) + ''''
 exec (@cmd)
```

Comment: you can use @ symbol to notify user,like @Rushang